# SAP BO login using custom.jsp

Tags: java, authentication, jsp, business-objects

I'm using `custom.jsp` in order to avoid the login screen and load the home screen directly, but still it's asking for login credentials after restarting the tomcat. The path of the `custom.jsp` file is "`SAP BusinessObjects\tomcat\webapps\BOE\WEB-INF\eclipse\plugins\webpath.InfoView\web`".

I don't know what I'm missing here and I'm new to this. Below is my jsp code. Thanks.

```
<%@ page import="com.crystaldecisions.sdk.exception.SDKException" %>
<%@ page import="com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.infostore.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.net.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.crystaldecisions.sdk.plugin.admin.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.businessobjects.webutil.Encoder" %>


<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>


<%

IEnterpriseSession enterpriseSession;


final String BO_CMS_NAME = "BI98svr";
final String BO_AUTH_TYPE = "secEnterprise";
final String BO_USERNAME = "user121";
final String BO_PASSWORD = "pass121";
ILogonTokenMgr logonTokenMgr;
String defaultToken = "";


boolean loggedIn = true;
try {

enterpriseSession =
CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr().logon(BO_USERNAME,BO_PASSWORD, 
BO_CMS_NAME,BO_AUTH_TYPE);
logonTokenMgr = enterpriseSession.getLogonTokenMgr();
defaultToken = logonTokenMgr.createWCAToken("", 20, 1);


response.sendRedirect("http://"+BO_CMS_NAME+":8080/BOE/BI/logon/start.do?ivsLogonToken="+Encoder.encodeURL(defaultToken));


}
catch (Exception error)
{
loggedIn = false;
out.println(error);
}
%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot fathom why you are hardcoding a username and password instead of just using SSO from active directory or similar.

Comment: @BryanCain Thanks for your response Bryan. Actually I'm doing kind of POC by putting hardcode values for now. Still I won't be able to run this code. Could you please help me out in this. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have hands on experience with the sort of thing you're trying to do, so I can't help.  That's why I only commented, not answered.   I was trying to point out that perhaps solving this problem isn't worth the time, since it's not something you really ought to be doing.